# Use birthtime as a unique file identifier? (node fs.stat)

Tags: node.js, filesystems, inode

I'm looking for a way to identify files with nodejs that works even if the file name and/or file path is changed. I'm hoping for a cross-platform solution (or at least Mac and Windows; Linux would be nice).

I was first hopeful that `ino` (ie `inode`, returned with `fs.stat(file)`) could work as a unique file identifier. (Discussion of that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43170582/is-there-any-way-to-retrieve-a-file-folders-unique-id-via-nodejs/43170811) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069898/can-inode-and-crtime-be-used-as-a-unique-file-identifier)). But it looks like inode is not reliable on Windows (status unclear, renders in 64-bit), and even on Mac I have seen that a file's inode can change when saving changes to a file.

So I'd need something that is unique to a file, that does not change.
What about `birthtime` (or `birthtimeMs`), returned from fs.stat?

This is when a file is created, down to the millisecond. It does not seem to change on Mac, and (**maybe?**) does not seem to change on [Windows or Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58263078/fs-stat-birthtime-birthtimems-in-linux-and-macos). (seems like Mac, Windows, and updated Linux support [birthtimeMs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55074206/in-node-js-how-can-i-know-whether-fs-stat-will-return-usable-crtime-and-or-bir).)

And birthtime would be unique to each file, so long as a user can only create one file at a time (at least more than 1 millisecond difference between file create times).

So, could birthtime be used as a unique file identifier on Mac and Windows (and maybe Linux too)?

Comment: probably the only way to reliably check if 2 files are same is to match checksum, and that's what mostly done today. When you download a file sometimes they will give u a text value a md5, sha checksum of the file for you to verify if the file you have downloaded is same or not. same concept here.

Comment: Thanks. I could be wrong, but to get a checksum of a file I need to read the file's whole content and then create a hash, correct? That probably would start eating up too much processing and time in my case.  Is there anything wrong with using birthtimeMs as an id for a file, to track a file as it changes (gets saved, changes name, changes path, etc)?